# Problem with displaying JFrame objects in Java

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I'm an IT student, I've recently been using Swing in Java, I tried to create a very simple class that extends JFrame, which takes a String in the constructor and adds the contents of the string inside a JLabel, contained in turn in the JFrame,

```
public class DocumentFrame extends JFrame {

   private JLabel textLabel;
   private JScrollPane scrollPane;

   public DocumentFrame(String title, String text) {
      super(title);
      setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      setSize(900,500);         
      setLayout(new BorderLayout());
      setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLACK);

      String processText = text.replaceAll("[.;]", "$0<br>");
    
      textLabel = new JLabel("<html>"+processText+"</html>");
      textLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.LEFT);
      textLabel.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.TOP);
      textLabel.setForeground(Color.WHITE);

      JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textLabel);
      add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);    
      pack();
      setVisible(true);
   }
}
```

If I try to instantiate an object of this class inside the main method where I created the class itself, everything is fine, the frame is displayed correctly;
if instead I try with the same instruction to instantiate an object of that class within a project I'm doing with some of my friends, I don't know why the frame appears, but it's all "buggated",
the image is not displayed, the X key at the top right of the frame does not work, to close the frame I would have to finish the execution of the program manually.

This is what I do in the main method contained in the class itself

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   String text = "I put a long text";
   new DocumentFrame("title frame", text);
}
```

and that's fine, if I do this from another part of my project it doesn't work.

Comment: *if instead I try with the same instruction to instantiate an object of that class within a project I'm doing with some of my friends,* - well the posted code doesn't show how you do that. I would guess the code is blocking the `Event Dispatch Thread (EDT)` and preventing the frame from painting itself. Maybe you have looping code that never finishes executing? Read the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information.

Comment: I'd never thought of putting a `JLabel` inside of a `JScrollPane`.  I think a `JTextArea` or `JTextPane` might be the Swing component you're looking for.

Comment: Really there should only be one `JFrame` per app, so you wouldn't normally be creating a `JFrame` from another anyway. If you want 'another information window' you should be probably creating a `JDialog` or even `JOptionPane`. You should really create all the functionality you want based upon a `JPanel` then you can put that panel anywhere and in any type of window